# Adding sections and heading dynamically in uitableview in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

I have an array(stringArray) and I am filling this array with the values which is coming from the database(**sqlite**).MY array containsmultiplication tables from **1-10** and my array format is

```
('1x1=1','1x2=2','1x3=3'.......'10x10=100')
```

There are total 10 multiplication tables(**1,2,3,4.....10**) so there will be total 10 heading(sections) in the table. My problem is that I don't know how to add heading to these multiplication table. If anyone has any idea regarding this share your ideas. I have gone through some links but still I am unclear.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` in your table view delegate?

Comment: @PhillipMills...I have calculated the sections and heading for the table say if a user click on 1-10(on a segment control)then i have created number of  headings in a for loop and returned these headings. The problem is that how to combine these headings with the data which is returning from the array. As I discussed earlier that I have an array which contains the data from the database. If you know that please tell me.Actually I am looking for that logic.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "combine".  Perhaps you could show what you're doing in code to make it easier to analyze.

Comment: @PhillipMills...I cant tell u the extact code because code exists in my company PC but I can tell you the problem. The thing is that I am fetching data from database and it contains all the multiplication table which I described earlier and returning that array count from "no of rows in selection" to "cell at index path" delegate method in that I am simply displaying the data. Just tell me where and what lines of code are to needed to display the data with the heading, If you have don this just tell me . I will be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Without seeing what you already have, I can't tell you how to fix it...that would require a miracle to get it right.  Sorry.